# Помогите разобраться с ошибкой Error creating bean with name 'booksController' в Spring приложении

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Друзья, привет! Небольшое Java CRUD приложение для библиотеки на Spring MVC и Spring DATA JPA, смысл которого в создании пользователей, привязки к ним взятых книг, контроле срока возврата и т.д. При попытке запустить приложение на локальном сервере TomCat получаю указанные ниже ошибки.
Самому разобраться не получается, советы найденные на просторах интернета не помогли, аннотации проверил, вроде как все ок. Прошу помочь.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'booksController' defined in file [C:\Users\user\spring-mvc-app1\SpringDataJpaHibernateApp\target\spring-project2\WEB-INF\classes\ru\vorobiev\springApp\controllers\BooksController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookRepositoriesImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\user\spring-mvc-app1\SpringDataJpaHibernateApp\target\spring-project2\WEB-INF\classes\ru\vorobiev\springApp\services\BookRepositoriesImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookRepositoriesImpl': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Root Cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookRepositoriesImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\user\spring-mvc-app1\SpringDataJpaHibernateApp\target\spring-project2\WEB-INF\classes\ru\vorobiev\springApp\services\BookRepositoriesImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookRepositoriesImpl': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:578)

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookRepositoriesImpl': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:355)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:227)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

SpringConfig:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ru.vorobiev.springApp"})
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:hibernate.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaRepositories("ru.vorobiev.springApp.repositories")
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private final Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext, Environment env) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.environment = env;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.driver_class"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    // Используем Hibernate вместо JdbcTemplate
//    @Bean
//    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
//        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
//    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));

        return properties;
    }

//    @Bean
//    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
//        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
//        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
//        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("ru.vorobiev.springcourse.model");
//        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
//
//        return sessionFactory;
//    }

    // код для корректной работы Spring Data JPA

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("ru.vorobiev.springApp.models");

        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

MyDispatcherServletInitializer:

```
public class MyDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext aServletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(aServletContext);
        registerCharacterEncodingFilter(aServletContext);
        registerHiddenFieldFilter(aServletContext);
    }

    private void registerHiddenFieldFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
        aContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter",
                new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
    }

    private void registerCharacterEncodingFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
        EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD);

        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncoding = aContext.addFilter("characterEncoding", characterEncodingFilter);
        characterEncoding.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");
    }
}
```

booksController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BooksController {

    private final BookRepositoriesImpl bookService;
    private final PeopleRepositoriesImpl peopleService;

    @Autowired
    public BooksController(BookRepositoriesImpl bookService, PeopleRepositoriesImpl peopleService) {
        this.bookService = bookService;
        this.peopleService = peopleService;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public String index(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page,
                        @RequestParam(value = "books_per_page", required = false) Integer booksPerPage,
                        @RequestParam(value = "sort_by_year", required = false) Boolean sortByYear) {
        if (page == null || booksPerPage == null)
            model.addAttribute("books", bookService.findAll(sortByYear)); //выдача всех книг
        else
            model.addAttribute("books", bookService.findWithPagination(page, booksPerPage, sortByYear));
        return "book/index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String show(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model, @ModelAttribute("person") Person person) {
        model.addAttribute("book", bookService.findOne(id));

        //получаем владельца книги(если он есть)
        Person bookOwner = bookService.getBookOwner(id);
        if (bookOwner != null)
            model.addAttribute("owner", bookOwner);
        else
            model.addAttribute("people", peopleService.findAll());
        return "book/show";
    }

    @GetMapping("/new")
    public String newBook(@ModelAttribute("book") Book book) {
        return "book/new";
    }

    @PostMapping()
    public String create(@ModelAttribute("book") @Valid Book book,
                         BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
            return "book/new";

        bookService.save(book);
        return "redirect:/books";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}/edit")
    public String edit(Model model, @PathVariable("id") int id) {
        model.addAttribute("book", bookService.findOne(id));
        return "book/edit";
    }

    @PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public String update(BindingResult bindingResult, @PathVariable("id") int id,
                         @ModelAttribute("book") @Valid Book updatedBook) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
            return "book/edit";

        bookService.update(id, updatedBook);
        return "redirect:/books";
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public String delete(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        bookService.delete(id);
        return "redirect:/books";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}/release")
    public String release(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        bookService.release(id);
        return "redirect:/books/" + id;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}/assign")
    public String assign(@PathVariable("id") int id, @ModelAttribute("person") Person selectedPerson) {
        bookService.assign(id, selectedPerson);
        return "redirect:/books/" + id;
    }

    public String makeSearch(Model model, @RequestParam("query") String query) {
        model.addAttribute("books", bookService.searchByTitle(query));
        return "book/search";
    }
}
```

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Название книги не должно быть пустым")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 20, message = "Название книги должно быть от 2 до 20 символов")
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Поле автор книги не должно быть пустым")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 100, message = "Поле автор должно быть от 2 до 100 символов")
    @Column(name = "author")
    private String author;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Год написания не должен быть пустым")
    @Min(value = 1500, message = "Год написания книги не может быть ранее, чем 1500")
    @Column(name = "year_of_writing")
    private int yearOfWriting;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_person", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Person owner;

    //текущее время в млс, когда книгу кто-то забирает.Для авт проверки на просроченность книги
    @Column(name = "taken_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date takenAt;

    //hibernate не видит это поле.В нем будет сохранятся значение просрочена книга или нет.
    @Transient
    private boolean expired;

    public Book() {

    }

    public Book(String name, String author, int yearOfWriting) {
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.yearOfWriting = yearOfWriting;
    }

    public Book(int id, String name, String author, int yearOfWriting, Person owner, Date takenAt, boolean expired) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.yearOfWriting = yearOfWriting;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.takenAt = takenAt;
        this.expired = expired;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public int getYearOfWriting() {
        return yearOfWriting;
    }

    public void setYearOfWriting(int yearOfWriting) {
        this.yearOfWriting = yearOfWriting;
    }

    public Person getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Person owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public Date getTakenAt() {
        return takenAt;
    }

    public void setTakenAt(Date takenAt) {
        this.takenAt = takenAt;
    }

    public boolean isExpired() {
        return expired;
    }

    public void setExpired(boolean expired) {
        this.expired = expired;
    }
}
```

BookRepositories:

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepositories extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer> {
    List<Book> findByTitleStartingWith(String author);//метод будет искать книги по начальным буквам в названии
}
```

BookRepositoriesImpl

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class BookRepositoriesImpl {

    private final BookRepositories booksRepositories;

    @Autowired
    public BookRepositoriesImpl(BookRepositories booksRepositories) {
        this.booksRepositories = booksRepositories;
    }


    public List<Book> findAll(boolean sortByYear) {
        //сортируем книги по году. В BookController либо передается параметр sortByYear либо нет
        if (sortByYear)
            return booksRepositories.findAll(Sort.by("yearOfWriting"));
        else
            return booksRepositories.findAll();
    }

    //метод для пагинации. Либо сортируем, либо нет
    public List<Book> findWithPagination(Integer page, Integer booksPerPage, boolean sortByYear) {
        if (sortByYear)
            return booksRepositories.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, booksPerPage, Sort.by("yearOfWriting"))).getContent();
        else
            return booksRepositories.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, booksPerPage)).getContent();
    }

    public Book findOne(int id) {
        Optional<Book> foundBook = booksRepositories.findById(id);
        return foundBook.orElse(null);
    }

    public void save(Book book) {
        booksRepositories.save(book);
    }

    //метод для функционала поиска книги
    public List<Book> searchByTitle(String author) {
        //вызываем метод из BookRepository для поиска книг по автору
        //никакю логику не реализуем, весь функционал дает Spring Data JPA.
        return booksRepositories.findByTitleStartingWith(author);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void update(int id, Book updatedBook) {
        Book bookToBeUpdated = booksRepositories.findById(id).get();

        //добавляем новую книгу (которая не находилась в Persistence context), поэтому нужен save()
        updatedBook.setId(id);
        updatedBook.setAuthor(bookToBeUpdated.getAuthor()); //что бы не терялась связь при обновлении
        booksRepositories.save(updatedBook);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void delete(int id) {
        booksRepositories.deleteById(id);
    }

    //метод возвращает null если у книги нет владельца
    public Person getBookOwner(int id) {
        return booksRepositories.findById(id).map(Book::getOwner).orElse(null);
    }

    //метод освобождает книгу (вызывается когда человек сдал книгу в библиотеку)
    @Transactional
    public void release(int id) {
        booksRepositories.findById(id).ifPresent(
                book -> {
                    book.setAuthor(null);
                    book.setTakenAt(null);
                }
        );
    }

    //метод устанавливает владельца, когда берут книгу
    @Transactional
    public void assign(int id, Person selectedPerson) {
        booksRepositories.findById(id).ifPresent(book -> {
            book.setOwner(selectedPerson);
            book.setTakenAt(new Date());
        });
    }
}
```